# Show indirect utility is increasing w and non-increasing in price?

Tags: microeconomics

Given indirect utility function $v(p,w)$, where p are prices, w is wealth, my attempt is as following:

From the Utility Maximization Problem (UMP): Set up Lagrangian:

$L = u(x) + \lambda[w - px]$

$L_w = \lambda > 0$, by local non-satiation

$L_p = -\lambda x  \leq 0$ since $x\geq 0$ and using $\lambda > 0$

Is this ok?

Comment: Yes the argumentation is good, but the relationship between $L$ and $v$ is missing. I would approach this using the optimal values of $x$ and $\lambda$ and use the envelope theorem.

Comment: The partial of indirect utility function wrt to these variables should be the same as the partial wrt to the Lagrangian function because they are continuously differentiable?